# Django server inaccessible

Tags: python, android, django, windows-7

I have a [Django 2.2.5](https://www.djangoproject.com) server running on a Windows 7 machine. I'd like to access it from my Android phone to make sure that the website being served by the Django server works well on the Android device. However, the website fails to load on the Android device.

I've look around and found some things to try, but nothing has worked. Here'a list of things I've tried, all of which have failed:

- `Debug = False
  ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`
- Allowing any traffic through port 8000 through firewall
- Turning firewall off
- Accessing from raspberry pi

I've also tried some testing on the Windows 7 machine:

- When `ALLOWED_HOSTS = []`, I can access the site with `localhost:8000/my_site` and `127.0.0.1:8000/my_site`, but not `my_ip_address:8000/my_site`. This may be expected behavior, and I am okay with that.
- When `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', my_ip_address]`, if I'm not mistaken, `localhost:8000/my_site` should work, `127.0.0.1:8000/my_site` should not work, and `my_ip_address:8000/my_site` should work. As expected, `localhost:8000/my_site` works and `127.0.0.1:8000/my_site` does not work. `my_ip_address:8000/my_site`, however, does not work.

Can anybody explain this to me and help me access my Django server from my Android phone?

I start the server with the command `python manage.py runserver`.

Comment: Please show how you are running the server.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to see the command I'm running to start the server?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: I use `python manage.py runserver`. The description has been updated to include that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you!! An answer on the question you mentioned worked for me.